# Cardboard - Uncomfortable VR on somes smartphones

Tags: google-cardboard

I experience some uncomfortable behaviour when launching google cardboard app on some smartphones.

On Nexus 5, the experience is ok and i get a nice 3D effect when looking inside the cardboard but on Samsung S3 and Sony Xperia S the experience is very uncomfortable.

I did a comparison of the images produced by both phones and here is the result :

[image]
<sub>(source: [numix.fr](https://numix.fr/VR_difference.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, on the top image (Nexus 5) the image produced by the 2 cameras is slightly different resulting in a convincing VR experience.

On some other phones (Samsung S3, Sony Xperia S) i have a huge difference between the left and right image, resulting in a very uncomfortable VR : its impossible to see the objects in 3D.

I can't figure out why there is such difference between phones.

For info, My Nexus 5 is on Android 5.1.1, Samsung Galaxy S3 is on 4.1.1 and Sony Xperia is on 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "viewer" is not configured correctly in the Cardboard app of the S3 and Xperia. Try to switch the viewer in the cardboard app.

What you see is what happens if the app tries to display a larger (physical) image than the screen can bound. You can probably see it better when you actually start a demo.

I am able reproduce the same (messed up) result on my Note 4 when I create a viewer with an excessive "Screen to lens distance" (e.g. 50mm) and "Inter-lens distance" (e.g. 100mm) with the Viewer Profile Generator:

https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/

You might try to play with the generator to find some settings that work.

I'm not sure if the screen size of those devices is sufficient in first place. If it is, and the viewer is also correct, then maybe the app has somehow false assumptions about the physical screen size (or the ppi value).

Comment: My phone wasn't able to get rid of the "Tap the screen" layover. I can see the image changing in the background, but very hard to configure when not seeing it clearly.